# Nested for loop inside an ssh -t for loop command

Tags: bash, ssh, rhel, for

I've been trying to save some time by creating a loop to edit ifcfg files using the sed command. For testing I started by trying the below loop:

```
for k in `cat *FILE CONTAINING HOSTNAME*`; do echo $k; ssh -t *USER*@$k "for l in `ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ | grep ifcfg-ens`; do echo $l; done"; done
```

All this did was return the hostname, a line space and that connection had closed.

I then tried the below:

```
for k in `cat *FILE CONTAINING HOSTNAME*`; do echo $k; ssh -t *USER*@$k "for l in \`ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts | grep ifcfg-ens\`; do echo $l; done"; done
```

This returned the hostname and then 8 line spaces (like it was printing the output as expected) but no actual output in the terminal.

If anyone has any ideas on how i can achive this it would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The end goal here is to essentially run a sed command to remove lines 1 to 13 from any ifcfg-ens* file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. And then use a similar for loop to add lines to files across around 10 hosts.

The output of ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ | grep ifcfg-ens returns the below on the remote host:

```
ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts | grep ifcfg-ens
ifcfg-ens1f0
ifcfg-ens1f1
ifcfg-ens2f0
ifcfg-ens2f1
ifcfg-ens7f0
ifcfg-ens7f1
ifcfg-ens8f0
ifcfg-ens8f1
```

All the best,
Jack

Comment: See [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for why `for var in $(cat file); do ...` is a bad idea. Basically, your whole approach is really not a good one. Can you please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do so we can offer a better solution? It looks like all you want to run on the remote host is `echo /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*ifcfg-ens*`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for coming back to me. I've updated the question with what my end goal is.